# How to change font size?

Tags: css, simple-machines-forum

How to change font size for my SMF forum theme? I see percentages which change only some parts of the text, can't find where to change post font, thread font etc...

Please just point me in the right direction, also what does xx%/yy% mean in regards to the font?

```
 /* SMFSimple.com Theme Style */

    body
     {
        background: url(../images/theme/bg.png) #f8f8f8;
   font: 78%/130% 'Oxygen',sans-serif;
   padding: 0px;
}

a:link, a:visited {color: #4D4D4D;}
a.new_win:link, a.new_win:visited {color: #4D4D4D;}

input, button, select, textarea
{
   font: 95%/115% 'Oxygen',sans-serif;
   color: #000;
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #7f9db9;
}

textarea
{
   font: 100%/130% 'Oxygen',sans-serif;
}

.smalltext, tr.smalltext th
{
   font-size: 0.85em;
   font-family: 'Oxygen',sans-serif;
}
.middletext
{
   font-size: 0.9em;
   line-height: 1em;
   font-family: 'Oxygen',sans-serif;
}
.normaltext
{
   font-size: 1em;
   line-height: 1.2em;
}
.largetext
{
   font-size: 1.4em;
}

code.bbc_code
{
   display: block;
   font-family: 'Oxygen',sans-serif;
   font-size: x-small;
   background: #eef;
   border-top: 2px solid #999;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   padding: 3px 1em;
   overflow: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
   /* Show a scrollbar after about 24 lines. */
   max-height: 24em;
}

.bbc_tt
{
   font-family: 'Oxygen',sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oxygen';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Oxygen'), local('OpenSans'), url(../fonttheme.woff) format('woff');
}

#full_header 
{
   margin: 0 auto;   
   min-width: 764px;
   max-width: 2300px;      
}

#bar_social 
{
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.ss_content_header
{
   clear: both; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px 0px;
   padding: 20px 0px;
}

.ss_logo 
{ 
   width: 48%; 
   float: left; 
   margin-top: 10px;
   padding-left: 20px;
}

.ss_user_area 
{ 
   width: 48%;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 15px;
}


.table_user 
{
   border-radius: 5px;
   background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.7);
   padding: 0px 10px;
   font-size: 12px;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #666;   
}

.user 
{
   color: #f4f4f4;
}
.user a 
{
   color: #F9BC06;
}

.ss_avatar_pad 
{
   padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Look at your posts, threads and so on, for css classes. Find that classes in your .css file and change the font. % "Sets the font-size to a percent of  the parent element's font size" xx% is the font size, and yy% is the line-height.

Comment: how to add .normaltext tag to this class: .inner
{
   padding: 1em 1em 2px 0;
   margin: 0 1em 0 0;
   border-top: 1px solid #99a;
} @MihaiAlex

Comment: Not sure what you mean: .inner .normaltext {  } This will affect an element with .normaltext class that is a child of an element with .inner class.

Comment: when going through my posts, I see that it is div class=inner and it is only mentioned in my css stylesheet in the following:
.inner
{
   padding: 1em 1em 2px 0;
   margin: 0 1em 0 0;
   border-top: 1px solid #99a;
}

How to change its font size? :)

Comment: .inner { font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.2em; padding: 1em 1em 2px 0; margin: 0 1em 0 0; border-top: 1px solid #99a; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
font: 78%/130% 'Oxygen',sans-serif;
```

breaks down to:

- `font-size: 78%;`
- `line-height: 130%;`
- `font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;`

If no font size is given explicitly, the browser's default value is used, which is actually `16px`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. How to attach .middletext into a specific class like .inner?

Comment: when going through my posts, I see that it is div class=inner and it is only mentioned in my css stylesheet in the following:
.inner
{
   padding: 1em 1em 2px 0;
   margin: 0 1em 0 0;
   border-top: 1px solid #99a;
}

How to change its font size? :)

Comment: @WebDeveloper Actually there's no `<div>` or a class `.inner` in your post. But you can change the font size by adding `font-size: 1.0 em; `  to `.inner {}`.